# WPF/WinForms DragDrop IDataObject

Tags: wpf, winforms, drag-and-drop

I was wondering why WPF defines a new and apparently identical version of IDataObject for its drag/drop system?

I have application code which uses the winforms IDataObject which I now need to interoperate with WPF drag/drop events.  Would it be safe to simply write an adapter class which implements System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject but passes calls into the actual System.Windows.IDataObject provided by WPF?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

## Scenario

I found this question when I was trying to debug this problem:

I was dropping into a WinForms application, where inside the Drop event handler, the object I received was a `System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject`

However, I was using a library to do the heavy lifting of the Drop event, and it expected a object of type `System.Windows.IDataObject`. I was not able to edit the library source code.

## Problem

If I tried to simply cast between the types ...

```
// data is of type System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject
var newData = (System.Windows.IDataObject)data; // debugger exits function after this line of code
```

... the debugger would just exit the function at that line of code without error. None of the code after that line would execute.

## Solution

I created a proxy method that I called inside my WinForms event handler. The constructor for `System.Windows.DataObject` will accept a `System.Windows.Forms.DataObject`.

```
public void DropEventProxy(System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data)
{
    System.Windows.IDataObject newData = new System.Windows.DataObject(data);    
    LibraryDropEventHandler(newData);
}

public string LibraryDropEventHandler(System.Windows.IDataObject data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for dragdrop inside of the same application, you can take a look at :
[WinForms Interop, Drag & Drop from WinForms -> WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213074/winforms-interop-drag-drop-from-winforms-wpf/4820128#4820128)

Note that you will probably be better implemanting serialization for your object.