# Lose data serialization when I send a data into Windows clipboard

Tags: c#, serialization, clipboard

I have a few problem with the Windows Clipboard in my WPF desktop application.
I try to retrieve clipboard content, do something (without write on this content, only read), and re-send the content into clipboard. It run, but after re-send the content, if I retrieve clipboard content and try to read again, I have an OutOfMemory exception.

After search, I've found this link : http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/09/05/system-outofmemoryexception-gotcha-using-clipboard-getdata-in-wpf/

It's maybe because of a serialization problem, I think that my data loose his serialisation attribut or else when I send it into the clipboard.

Here is my code :

```
var data = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
// Read "data"
System.Windows.Clipboard.Clear();
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);

var dataTwo = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
// Read "dataTwo" ==> OutOfMemoryException
```

Notice that the data has not a Type of my project, it can be everything (photoshop, excel, picture, text, binary...)

Anyone has an idea to correct this?

Thank you un advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you mentioned and conclusions in there, it looks as if the `data` variable type must be marked as `[Serrializable]`.

As you need it to be pretty much "everything" you can try using an interface [`ISerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx)

```
class Foo
{
    private ISerrialisable data;
    ...
}
```

So as long as the object is serrializable you should be able to use it with clipboard.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer. I've tried what you said, but it strange, I have and MDA Excpetion, based on the code of this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213074/winforms-interop-drag-drop-from-winforms-wpf
Maybe I forgot somthing ?

Comment: Anyone have an idea? I'm blocked