# Is it possible to change mouse cursor when handling drag (from DragOver event)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, drag-and-drop

We need to display a feedback to the user when he drags-in items into our application. 
Our client prefers this feedback to be in form of a custom cursor.

This is already implemented for drag-out, using a custom cursor that is set in `GiveFeedback` event handler (raised by `DoDragDrop` when dragging items out of our app). The `GiveFeedbackEventArgs` allows us to specify `UseDefaultCursors` property - setting this to false allows us to override the cursor.

However, the `DragOver` event handler argument, which is the equivalent of `GiveFeedback`, does not have `UseDefaultCursors` property and changing the cursor from there does not have any effect.

**Sample (this has no effect):**

```
private void browser_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
}
```

The drag operation originates from outside our app. (for in-app drag, it works using the `GiveFeedback` event.

How to change the cursor when receiving a drag? Is this even possible/feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must implement a COM interfaces (IDragSourceHelper and IDropTargetHelper).
Take a look [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
void Form1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e) {
    e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.givefeedback(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Would this suffice?
This code will change the mouse pointer by adding a [+] sign next to it.

```
private void Form_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Comment: no, the requirement is to use a custom cursor (different graphics)

Comment: Ok, well no, that is a tricky one indeed. Would be interesting to hear about what you may find though. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

We've addressed a whole range of drag-drop issues here:

[Drag and Drop between Instances of the same Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201812/drag-and-drop-between-instances-of-the-same-windows-forms-application)

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you, but nothing mentioned in the linked question helped me